# Jquery to Java method call issue

Tags: java, jquery, javafx

I have a jquery function which calls a java method as defined below.

```
JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
window.setMember("clickController", new RecordProcessor());
executejQuery( webEngine, new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("record.js"))));
```

`webEngine` is a JavaFX web engine used to load some website.

RecordProcessor is as below:

```
public class RecordProcessor {
    public void process(Object object, String returnValue, String action) {
            System.out.println(action);
    }
}
```

Now in my record.js, I have a jquery function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('*').click(function(event) {
        clickController.process(event.target, "someString", "click");
    });
}
```

`clickController` is the handle used to access the `process` method of RecordProcessor.

The problem is, when I click once on an element in the webpage, the `process` method is getting called multiple times. I have no idea why. Can anyone please explain what is going on? Also, a possible solution?
Here, for example, "click" is getting printed in the console many times, and it is not in constant number. Each time I execute, it prints different number of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$('*').click(function(event) { ...
```

The `*` is telling jQuery to bind the 'click' to **every element** on the page.  The DOM is hierarchical, and the event will propagate by default to all the elements up the DOM.

---

Have you considered binding to `document` instead?

```
$(document).click(function(event) { ...
```

Comment: how to do the same for $("input[type=text]") ?

Comment: Hey @NaveenBharadwaj, your comment above sounds like it's regarding a different issue - perhaps you should create a new question and fill in the details there as I'm not sure I understand what's being asked.  Good luck.